# Checking a solution of a combinatorial question

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification

Here is a combinatorial question + solution that I got:

**Find the number of ternary sequence using digits "0", "1" and "2". No "012" and "21" subsequences are allowed in the sequence. How many sequences are there with $4$ digits?**

[image]

the solution is $49$. Is it? By simply writing all $4$ digits  sequences I got $50$ "legal" sequences, not $49$. Am I wrong?

Comment: I also got $50$:  There are $3^4=81$ sequences with no restriction.  To count the bad sequences, note there are $9$ of the form $21XX$ and $9$ of the form $X21X$ and $8$ of the form $XX21$ (excluding $2121$ which we counted before).  Then there are $3$ of the form $X012$ and $2$ of the form $012X$ (not counting $0121$ which we already counted). Thus there are $9+9+8+3+2=31$ bad sequences.

Comment: Thanks. So what is wrong with the solution given?

Comment: I did not check the recursion, but at a guess they double counted $0121$.  I made that mistake on my first count, for instance.

Comment: The solution also double counted the first c in recurrence.